# GHUnit : Testing Magical Record Code

Tags: objective-c, tdd, restkit, magicalrecord, gh-unit

I would like to test my repositories that use MagicalRecord framework.

I'm doing the following (from this article : http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/15/unit-testing-with-core-data/ ) :

```
@interface OMSTests : GHTestCase
@end

@implementation OMSTests

- (void)setUp;
{
[MagicalRecord setDefaultModelFromClass:[self class]];
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore];

}

- (void)tearDown;
{
[MagicalRecord cleanUp];
}

-(void)testXXX {
    NSManagedObjectContext * context = [NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext];

    [context save]; // context is not set 0x000000000000 

    OMSPointsEventEntity * entity = [OMSPointsEventEntity createEntity];

}
@end
```

I have the following error message when creating the entity :

```
Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
File: Unknown
Line: Unknown
Reason: [RKManagedObjectStore defaultObjectStore] cannot be nil
```

Anyone can help me to find why I don't have a context instanciated ? I did not find useful documentation for this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oups I realized that #define MR_SHORTHAND (allow me to call [context save] instead of [context MR_save])was not working, so it was my problem....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to use RestKit and MagicalRecord together. You may want to set up RestKit's managed object context separately and/or base it off the default context provided by MagicalRecord.